# loading data table checkbox if it has in database, checked already

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox, datatables

i am doing my school project. I manage to add/delete in database from my data-table checkbox if the value is check then it will add then if uncheck then it will be deleted, Now what i want is , when i go load the data table with checkbox, i want to check already the values that is already in my database. For example, if i have user_id = 102 already in my database, if i load the data-table, i want the name with user_id value of 102 will be automatically check when fetching the data-table checkbox. How can i do it? i am using a codeigniter framework.

Here is my controller in populating my data-table:

```
public function getalldocs() {
        $listdocs = $this->Admin_model->getdoctors();
        $data = array();
        foreach ($listdocs as $docs) {
            $row = array();  
            $row[] = $docs->user_fname;
            $row[] = $docs->user_mname;
            $row[] = $docs->user_lname;
            $row[] = '<input name="user_id[]" value="'.$docs->user_id.'" type="checkbox">';

            $data[] = $row;
        }
        $output = array(   
            "data" => $data,
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

Here is my ajax/javascript:

```
function show_docs() {
    $("#dataTables-docs").dataTable().fnDestroy();

    table =  $('#dataTables-docs').DataTable({ 
      "ajax": {
              "url": "<?php echo site_url('admin_controls/getalldocs')?>",
              "type": "POST",
          },
          responsive: true,
          className: 'select-checkbox',
          'bInfo': false,
          'paging': false
      });
}
```

and then i put the function into document-ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#dataTables-docs').dataTable();
  show_docs();

});
```

what i want is when i will go load my data-table, i want to check all the data-table checkbox if it is already in the database.

Comment: where are the users coming from if they are not already in the database when you make the ajax call?  And why do you crate the table then immediately destroy it?

Comment: Consider whether you really need to 'delete' it, as opposed to simply hiding it from view.

Comment: @Strawberry its ok to delete sir, just showing to class that i can delete, i want to already check the checkbox if it was already in database.

Comment: One fairly standard approach is to spit the result set out as a bit of json, and then handle behaviours in JavaScript- perhaps via a JS framework.

Comment: @Strawberry how can i do that ? please help me.. I didn't solve this yet

Answer (score 0):

You're just comparing arrays. I'm not PHP coder, so what follows might be a poor method, but it demonstrates the principle of comparing one array with another. Actually, it compares an array with an interating value, but that iterating value could just as easily be borrowed from another array...

```
<?php

$my_array = array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 5,
    4 => 7
);

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){ 
echo $i;
if(in_array($i,$my_array)){echo " yes <br>\n";} else {echo " no <br>\n";}
}

?>
```

Comment: its very different in implementing it to codeigniter, for considering the data table